# Prove that if $A$ has the same cardinality as $\emptyset $, then $A= \emptyset$

Tags: proof-verification

Let Equivalence($\equiv$) be defined as having the same cardinality.

Assume,  $A \equiv \emptyset $. Then, there exists a function $f: A \to \emptyset $ such that f is a bijection.
This proof will now proceed by contradiction. Suppose, $ A \ne \emptyset$. Let $ x \in A$. Thus, for some $y \in \emptyset$,  $(x,y) \in f$. However, the statement $y \in \emptyset$ is a contradiction. Therefore, $ A = \emptyset$

Is this proof correct? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proof is correct.  Note that it actually shows that if $f:A\to\emptyset$ is *any* function, then $A=\emptyset$.  One point in the proof you might make more explicit is that if $A\not=\emptyset$, that means (by definition of $\emptyset$) that $A$ has an element, so you can choose one and call it $x$.